# How can show single SQL query result in php

Tags: php, sql

I have this query with this php code and can't show the result in echo, I can convert to string?

```
//conexion is my function to conect to DB and is done


$costTotal=conexion();
$costTotal=$costTotal->query("SELECT SUM(product_cost) FROM product");

echo $costTotal;
```

For example expected `string(5)"18000"`

Comment: You have to call a `fetch` function to fetch a row of results. This should be explained in any PHP mysqli tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

`$costTotal` contains the result of the database query which is not a string but you're using `echo`. To get the result as a string, you need to fetch the data from the query result.

```
$connection = connexion();

$query = "SELECT SUM(product_cost) as total FROM product";
$result = $connection->query($query);
$data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$costTotal = $data['total']; 

echo $costTotal;
```

Comment: using FETCH_ASSOC makes no sense in this context

Comment: Thanks friends I resolve add fetch function 

$costTotal=$costTotal->fetch();

Is array and next use $costTotal[0]; to the echo

I use var_dump($costTotal) to see the result 
array(2) { ["SUM(product_cost)"]=> string(8) "27000.00" [0]=> string(8) "27000.00" }